# Pi 3 Model B+ has steady red PWR LED but no green ACT LED with 2018-03-13-raspbian-stretch.img

Tags: pi-3b+

Pi 3 Model B+ has steady red PWR LED but no green ACT LED with 2018-03-13-raspbian-stretch.img. See screenshot below. I'm not sure if the side of the ACT light is red and if so if that's also a problem?

After some web research I was told to use the specific stretch image, which DOES work fine on the same SD card on my Pi 3 Model B V1.2 (2015).

I am using this power adapter shown below.

**I guess let's start with an answer to this question: What is a known working Raspbian image (or I guess ANY distro/flavor with minimum dropping of other files into the image, etc..) that works with my model?**

Background: I bought this for the purposes of the 5GHZ wifi and it will be (hopefully) powering my 7 inch Pi Display V1.1 which I had working with other Pi models.

UPDATE: 
1. New microSD card flashed with: 2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-full.img
2. updated firmware[image: updatedfirmware]
3. went through troubleshooting steps again from suggestion in comment
no dice

[image]

[image]

Comment: does the ACT led flash at all?

Comment: If the red is never flashing on occasions, then I suggest you take another SD card and prepare another system / boot. Usually when there is nothing green - it simply can not find the boot. this can happen for a variety of reasons. none of them is the specific image

Comment: No the ACT led does not flash at all. Now - on the FIRST (not this one) Pi 3 Model B+ the ACT led flashed twice - which IIRC means it could not read the SD card? I am returning the old one once I get the new one working - and the new one again has no activity on the ACT led. @JaromandaX

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I thought that the steady red PWR LED is normal, on this model at least, no?

Comment: @JohnZaj Yes, it is. Hence if it is not flashing, probably not power problem. see also my answer.

Answer (score 2):

All Raspbian images work on all models (except models newer than the image).

If you update/upgrade an older image (to  ensure the firmware is updated) it would work (the Pi4 needs Buster and the 3B+ Stretch).

The Pi3B+ was released on 14 March 2018 (Pi day) so I would expect that should work.

NOTE the Red LED is not a reliable power indicator on the Pi3B+ as it controlled by software and needs up to date firmware to work.

Comment: before I panic, I'll take your suggestion and let you know :). Thanks for the info, already helpful

Comment: So if the form factor of the Pi4 is compatible with my 7" pi display V1.1 (2015) I should really just get that. I overlooked this.

Answer (score 2):

Your power supply should be enough, assuming it is operating in the rated written current. you can always verify it with a multimeter, or checking that the red LED is never blinking.

That being said - make sure the plug is secured tightly. The LED is not 100% fail-proof indicator.

As for the other issue - if the Green LED never on / blinks, then probably it can not find a valid img / boot on the SD card.

This can happen for several reasons, like wrong writing permissions when card was written, faulty card, faulty single sector / file ( like `bootcode.bin` for example ) and many other causes.

I would suggest taking a new SD card if possible and make a new system/boot as in most occasions I encountered - the SD / img was the fault. second is power. Don't forget that an img can be corrupted for many reasons while prepared, downloaded, transferred.

Also pass over the steps / verification on [this list](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_on.2C_green_LED_does_not_flash.2C_nothing_on_display)

As for the distro / img - any image that specifically support your hardware will do - not necessarily raspbian, but if you want to verify hardware - you can find many listed [here](https://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions).

Also, if problem persist, try to turn on without nay connections except the PWR usb. Take out `HDMI`, `USB`, `LAN` etc. and look at the green LED.

Comment: "suggest taking a new SD card" despite that the same image on the same SD card works fine on other Pi's?. 
No change with HDMI / all other peripherals out.
Power is 'good' according to my multimeter, but I'll get a better one that checks average and test on that for dips and blips I guess.

Comment: @JohnZaj - if you have another  image / sd card than try it on the problematic one. Also, try some other system from the list... just to verify hardware functioning. and yes. I suggested it despite that. It is just a sensible first debugging verification.